# Create virtual machine on Hyper-V Server through a Powershell Script triggered by a vNext build

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I think the question is already clear but if not I'll explain a little more.
I am trying to deploy test agents on a virtual machine using build vNext. In order to do that I need to create a virtual machine on the Hyper-V server.

I'm doing that by executing a Powershell script in a Powershell vNext task.

When I execute the script in my PC, there's no problem. But when I execute it in the build agent I got an error that seems to be because of a parameter.

Here is my powershell script:

```
Import-Module virtualmachinemanager
Import-Module virtualmachinemanagercore

$VMName= "VMTestName"
$cloud= "testCloud"
$Template= "testTemplate"
$VMMComputer = "testServer"
$VMMPort = 8100

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "passWord!" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("useR", $secpasswd)

$VMMServer = Get-SCVMMServer -ComputerName $VMMComputer -TCPPort $VMMPort -ConnectAs Administrator -Credential $credentials -UserRoleName "Administrator"

$TemplateObj = Get-SCVMTemplate -VMMServer $VMMServer -All | where { $_.Name -eq $Template }
$virtualMachineConfiguration = New-SCVMConfiguration -VMTemplate $TemplateObj -Name $VMName
$cloudObj = Get-SCCloud -Name $cloud

Write-Verbose "Creating VM $VMName in cloud $cloud"
New-SCVirtualMachine -Name $VMName -VMConfiguration $virtualMachineConfiguration -Cloud $cloudObj -Computername $VMName| out-null

Start-VM $VMName
```

And the error is:

**Get-SCVMMServer : VMM encountered an exception The formatter threw an  exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while  trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:ConnectAs. The  InnerException message was 'Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. '. Please see InnerException for more details.  and couldn't complete the request. (Error ID: 20414)**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the SCVMM Addin for TFS 2015

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.scvmmapp

- **SCVMM Service Connection ***: Select the SCVMM service connection defined above from the drop down.
- **Action ***: Select - Restore Checkpoint.
- **Virtual Machines Name**: Provide the name of the Virtual Machine or a comma separated list of the Virtual Machines, like fabrikamdev, fabrikamqa, prod05 etc
- **Virtual Machine Template Name**: To create Virtual Machine using template, provide the virtual machine template name
- **Placement path for VM**: Specify virtual machine path to be used during virtual machine placement. For example, path on the host machine: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
- **Additional Arguments**: Additional argument for new virtual machine creation using template. For example, -StartVM -StartAction NeverAutoTurnOnVM -StopAction SaveVM etc.
- **Script Path**: Path of the PowerShell script to execute. Should be fully qualified path or relative to the default working directory
- **Script Arguments**: Arguments passed to the PowerShell script. Either ordinal parameters or named parameters
- **Working folder**: Current working directory when script is run. Defaults to the folder where the script is located.
- **Wait Time**: Wait time to get the virtual machine to ready state.
- **Checkpoint Name**: For 'Create CheckPoint', enter the name of the checkpoint that will be applied to the Virtual Machines. In case of 'Delete Checkpoint' or 'Restore Checkpoint' ensure that the Checkpoint name is valid.
- **Select VMs From**: You can scope the source for Virtual Machines from either VMM Cloud or VMM hosts.
- **Set Computer name as defined in VM template**: You can check this box to set computer name as defined in the specified VM template. If not selected, Computer name will be same as that of the 'Virtual Machine Names'.